# can't enable imap via access token

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, gmail, imap

I'm trying to access gmail imap via access token from login.
I pass the token to backend but it shows `username and password are not accepted`
Front End using react:

```
const {name,email,message,accessToken} = this.state;
    const form = await Axios.post("/api/form",{
      name,
      email,
      message,
      accessToken
    });
```

backend using nodejs:

```
var imap = new Imap({
        user: 'SMTH@gmail.com',
        host: 'imap.gmail.com',
        xoauth2 :request.body.accessToken,
        port: 993,
        tls: true,
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing which IMAP library you're using specifically, please keep the following in mind:

- you must specifically request the `mail.google.com` scope to get access to a user's email
- most JS based IMAP clients (with the exception of a few like emailjs-imap-client) don't auto-encode the XOAUTH token for you and you'll need to do this manually, for gmail this is: `user={email}^Aauth=Bearer {token}^A^A`. To get the `^A` token in javascript you can use `\u0001` like so:

```js
const xoauth2 = `user=${email}\u0001auth=Bearer ${accessToken}\u0001\u0001`
```

Keep in mind you will also need to base64 encode this before sending it to a server like so:

```
btoa(xoauth2)
```

You can check if your credentials are correct via IMAP yourself as well. To connect use the following command from a bash client with openSSL installed:

```
openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993 -crlf
```

This will open an IMAP session where you can then send commands.
An example of logging in via XOAUTH2 (using the encoded base64 form from above):

```
? AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 dXNlcj1zb21ldGhpbmdAZ21haWwuY29tAWF1dGg9QmVhcmVyIHNvbWVfYWNjZXNzX3Rva2VuAQE=
```

The server will respond with an `OK` and a message if your credentials are correct.